# Multiplying 2 digits in TextField - Java FX

Tags: java, javafx

I am struggling with a bug in my application.
The general idea was to multiply base price by slider argument, for example if the slider is set to 2, price = 2 * price

The problem is that is if I switch the slider again, math operations are accumulating. For example when I switched slider to 2, then to 3, after that to 4, my result is price * 2 * 3 * 4, but my expectation is to have price * 4 remembered. How can I fix it?

```
daysSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

@Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
      int i = Integer.parseInt(priceTextField.getText());
        priceTextField.textProperty().setValue(
                String.valueOf((int) daysSlider.getValue()* i ));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem that you are having is getting the String from the Text Field and doing math operations with it.

The way that you can go around this problem is by **parsing the String** to an Integer by doing the following:

```
int baseCost = Integer.parseInt(textField.getValue());
```

This will give you the base cost as an Integer and then, you can multiply it by the number in the slider by using the similar method. Now, you can set the value in `priceTextField` by doing the following:

```
//totalCost is an integer value calculated by multiplying the base cost and the slider's value.
priceTextField.textProperty().setValue(Integer.toString(totalCost));
```

I hope this helps!

**With your new problem,** this is why it is happening:

The reason that you are getting the problem is because each time the value in the slider is changed, you are setting `priceTextField` to `daySlider` times `i`. Then, the next time that there is a change, you are setting `i` equal to the value currently in the `priceTextField`. This is why it is doing multiple multiplications.

If I remember correctly, what you were trying to do is multiply the TextField value by the Slider Value and display it in another TextField. Therefore, what you can do is say `int i = Integer.parseInt(textField.getValue())` to get the value for your base cost. Then, you can multiply it with the `daysSlider` value and do `priceTextField.textProperty().setValue(
                    Integer.toString(i * sliderValue);`

**To solve your new problem:**

```
ArrayList<Integer> baseCost = new ArrayList<>();

priceTextField.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        baseCost.add(Integer.parseInt(priceTextField.getText()));
    }
}
daysSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        priceTextField.textProperty().setValue(
                String.valueOf((int) daysSlider.getValue() * baseCost.get(0) ));
    }

});
```

**ANSWER to your 3rd question (can be found in the chat)**:

This is how you make a runnable:

```
daysSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue arg0, Object arg1, Object arg2) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              priceTextField.textProperty().setValue(
              String.valueOf((int) daysSlider.getValue() * baseCost.get(0) ));
            }
        };

        Handler handler = new Handler();
        //Run the runnable after 3000 milliseconds or 3 seconds.
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);

    }

});
```